# Identify a separable Hilbert space with the space $\mathcal l^2$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces

Let $X$ separable Hilbert space with orthonormal basis $(e_i)$. Then any $x \in X$ can be written as $$x=\sum_{\mathbb N}x_i e_i$$ for $x_i \in \mathbb R$ and thus it is quite natural to identify $X$ with the sspace of sequences $\mathcal l^2$. Can an somebody point out a good reference for this?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_space#Separable_spaces

Comment: http://mathonline.wikidot.com/separable-hilbert-spaces-are-isometrically-isomorphic-to-2